# How to use beautiful soup and requests to extract article in website which is split in different pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

How to use beautiful soup and requests to extract each article to get full article in website which is split in different pages?

for example, this website
http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/F_Scott_Fitzgerald/The_Lees_Of_Happiness/Authors_Note_p1.html

thank you!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It definitely helps us better answer your question when you give a little bit more background (specifically, code that you have tried). Sometimes a question like this looks like homework, which can prevent you from getting the help you need. Check out this site on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should consider using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here a snippet to help you:

```
import requests

TOC = ["Chapter_I_p%d.html", "Chapter_III_p%d.html", ...]

# get all page for chapter I
for i in range(1, 10): # 10 because i noticed it.
    url = "http://www.pagebypagebooks.com/F_Scott_Fitzgerald/The_Lees_Of_Happiness/Chapter_I_p%d.html" % i
    r = requests.get(url)
    if not r.status_code in (200, 201):
        continue
    content = r.content
    with open(os.path.split(url)[-1], "wb") as fin:
        # write the whole content. 
        # bs4 can be used here to select 'p' tags...
        fin.write(content)
```

Note: for each chapter you can loop over the page as describe.

My approach to scrap pages is to identify the pattern beetwen the urls (here the page number) or with bs4 selector get next page to fetch it.

Comment: thank you! i thought find next page button and read text until to end

Comment: @EveBao, if the response suited to you, better is to accept it :)